# SQL Server Architecture

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

This is kind of a tough one to explain. I'm going to try to correlate our issue into a general spec.

I've got a table of questions that needed to be asked based on certain circumstances. For instance, let's say that I have 2 apples. **1 apple is blue** and the **other apple is red**.

Now, I need to be able to assign a question if we have 1 red apple. However, I also need to be able to assign a question for the combination of 1 red apple **and** 1 blue apple.

What's the best way to architect this? I feel that I've gotten close, but I'm still struggling to complete it.

The FilterGroupID is where they need to be grouped. So, down below, the questionID 3 needs to be queried when we've been given BLUE & SMALL.

[image]

**SCENARIO**
I'm given a certain combination of an apple. It's Blue and Small. I need to be able to query these questions that are correlated to this apple. So, I would need ANY question that has a filter type/value that matches. So in this scenario, I would want the following questions:

1. **Blue apple questions**
2. **Small apple questions**
3. **Blue AND Small apple questions**

If you look @ the image below, I've been given an apple that is BLUE & LARGE. The only questions I care (that are stored in the table) about are "Blue apple question". Now, if I was given a blue & small apple, I would care about "blue apple question" AND "blue & small" apple questions. The question "Blue & small apple question" is only shown IF THE APPLE IS BLUE AND SMALL. Meaning, It's not shown if the apple is BLUE AND LARGE.

[image]

Comment: It seems that what you are trying to model is a many to many relationship between Questions and GivenValues. But from the details posted it is really hard to understand the relationship between these tables.

Comment: @SeanLange I just added a scenario to try and help you.

Comment: @SeanLange I also just added a little more detail to try and help.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of the model, with a slightly different terminology so I can understand what I am talking about :-) :

```
Table: Qualities (Quality)
Records: (Color), (Size).

Table: QualityOptions(ID int, Quality, Option)
Records: (1, Color, Red), (2, Color, Blue), (3, Color, Green), (4, Size, Big),    
          (5, Size, Small)

Table: Questions (Question, QualityOptionID)
Records: (Q1, 1), (Q1, 5), (Q2, 1), (Q3, 4), (Q4, 5), (Q5, 2), (Q5, 4), (Q6, 2)
```

To improve readability of the example I rewrite the last table and its records as:

```
Table: Questions (Question, QualityOption)
Records: (Q1, Red), (Q1, Small), (Q2, Red), (Q3, Big), (Q4, Small), (Q5, Blue), 
         (Q5, Big), (Q6, Small)

Table: Items (Item)
Records: (a small blue item), (a blue item), (a red item), (a big blue item)

Table: ItemQualities (Item, QualityOption) - again, simplified!
Records: (a small blue item, small), (a small blue item, blue), (a blue item, blue),
         (a red item, red), (a big blue item, big), (a big blue item, blue)
```

Suppose that `Item = "a small blue item"`. Query `ItemQualities` relation to get the qualities `small` and `blue`. Query the `Questions` relation to get candidates: `(Q1,small)`, `(Q4,small)`, `(Q5,blue)`, `(Q6,small)`. You are not finished though: query again `Questions` to see if there are any other records for the candidate questions `Q1`, `Q4`, `Q5`, `Q6`. For `Q1` there is also `(Q1,red)`, meaning that we must discard `Q1`. For `Q5` there is also `(Q5, big)` -> discard. So we have our result set: `{Q4, Q6}`.

Suppose now that `Item = "a big blue item"`, so the `ItemQualities` table returns `big` and `blue`. Candidates from `Questions` are `(Q3,big), (Q5,blue), (Q5,big)`. Query again `Questions` to get every other record related to the candidates `Q3, Q5`. There are no other records returned and we can return `{Q3, Q5}` as the result.

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/IZPWL16152):**

```
create table Items (Item varchar(100))
create table ItemQualities (Item varchar(100), QualityOption varchar(20))
create table Questions (Question varchar(20), QualityOption varchar(20))

insert Items select 'a small blue item' union all select 'a big blue item'
insert ItemQualities select 'a small blue item', 'small' union all select 'a small blue item', 'blue'
union all select 'a big blue item', 'big' union all select 'a big blue item', 'blue'

insert Questions select 'Q1', 'red' union all select 'Q1','small' 
union all select 'Q2', 'red' union all select 'Q3', 'big' union all select 'Q4', 'small'
union all select 'Q5', 'Blue' union all select 'Q5', 'big' union all select 'Q6', 'small'

select * from items
select * from itemqualities
select * from questions

declare @item varchar(100) = 'a small blue item';


; with x as (
select count(*) cnt, q.Question
from ItemQualities iq join Questions q on iq.QualityOption = q.QualityOption
where item = @item
group by q.Question
)
,
y as 
(
select count(*) cnt, x.Question 
    from x
join Questions q on x.Question = q.Question
    group by x.Question
)
select distinct x.Question from x join y on x.Question = y.Question and x.cnt = y.cnt
```

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out what you mean by "query again." Do you mean a join?

Comment: I didn't go into the details, I was interested primarily in the model. I demonstrated how you would use it to get your result, not giving the actual SQL statements - I think that these more or less follow. I will try to give you a more complete example tomorrow, it is 3am in Greece now!

Comment: Gotcha. I created a better example of where I'm at in a new question with actual sql statements, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568706/sql-server-remove-results-with-nulls-in-group

Comment: Well, I completed the example (despite the need to sleep). [Here](http://rextester.com/IZPWL16152) is a demo. You specify the variable @item (a value in the `Items` table) and the relevant questions are returned.