# SQL Server - Remove results with NULLs in group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure if the title is proper, but I was a little unsure of how to word it. I've got a table of `circumstances` and I need to show certain questions based on the group of the `circumstances` given the passed in data.

**My passed in data looks like this:**

```
----------------------------------------------------
| CircumstanceTypeGiven | CircumstanceValueGiven |
----------------------------------------------------
|      Equipment        |           X            |
----------------------------------------------------
|      Customer         |        BEEFORE         |
----------------------------------------------------
```

**My `CircumstanceMaster` table looks like this:**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | CircumstanceType  |  GroupID  |  Value    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  |    Equipment      |    1      |  Reefer   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  |    Customer       |    1      |  BEEFOR   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**I've then got a table that holds question ID's for the groups like so:**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | CircumstanceGroupID  |    QuestionID      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  |         1            |         1          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**My question table:**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | Question                                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  This is my question for Reefer & BEEFOR  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

So, I'm getting passed an equipment type of *X* and a customer value of *BEEFOR*. My circumstance table says that if I'm passed *reefer* **and** *BEEFORE*, then I need to get the questions for `groupID` 1. However, I don't want the questions if only 1 is passed in (the scenario I'm giving).

Here's the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE CircumstanceMaster
(
    CircumstanceID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    CircumstanceGroupID INT NOT NULL,
    CircumstanceType INT NOT NULL,
    CircumstanceValue VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO CircumstanceMaster ( CircumstanceType, CircumstanceGroupID, CircumstanceValue ) VALUES ( 1, 1, 'R' )
INSERT INTO CircumstanceMaster ( CircumstanceType, CircumstanceGroupID,  CircumstanceValue ) VALUES ( 2, 1, 'DEEFOR' )


CREATE TABLE QuestionMaster
(
    QuestionID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Question VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO QuestionMaster ( Question ) VALUES ( 'Reefer & DEEFOR question' )


CREATE TABLE CircumstanceQuestion
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    CircumstanceGroupID INT NOT NULL,
    QuestionID INT NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO CircumstanceQuestion ( CircumstanceGroupID, QuestionID  ) VALUES ( 1, 1 )

declare @given Table(CircumstanceTypeGivenID INT, CircumstanceValueGiven varchar(50))
insert into @given(CircumstanceTypeGivenID,CircumstanceValueGiven) VALUES ( 1, 'X')
insert into @given(CircumstanceTypeGivenID,CircumstanceValueGiven) VALUES ( 2, 'DEEFOR')



select *
from CircumstanceMaster cm
    left outer join @given g on cm.CircumstanceType=g.CircumstanceTypeGivenID and cm.CircumstanceValue=g.CircumstanceValueGiven
```

I'm getting this result when I join up to my `circumstancemaster` table. I expect the result, but I need a way to say "If any of the rows in the SAME group have null values, don't return anything":

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| CircumstanceID | CircumstanceGroupID  | CircumstanceValueGiven|
----------------------------------------------------------------
|       1        |           1          |         NULL          |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|       2        |           1          |        BEEFOR         | 
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what do you mean if all rows has a even one null value dont display all result? or just display the row doesn't have a null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select CircumstanceGroupID 
from CircumstanceMaster cm 
left join @given g on cm.CircumstanceType=g.CircumstanceTypeGivenID and cm.CircumstanceValue=g.CircumstanceValueGiven
group by CircumstanceGroupID
having sum(case when CircumstanceValueGiven is null then 0 else 1 end) = count(*)
```

Back in your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566126/) you can find another approach.